# how to emulate home button on back button pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to make my app not close when the user pressed the back button and remain in the same state at least for a while, like the home button. I searched and some people suggested to do this.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

but this didn't help. I have to mention the activity I'm using this code on is not the `LAUNCHER` activity and before this activity, there is a splash screen.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: android studio is just an IDE, it just helps you to write your code, so your code won't be any different because you're using android studio, so there's no need to include it in your title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my code in your activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown: ");
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        goHome();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private void goHome() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Do start the home screen when key back down.

Answer (score -1):

You should not call super method in `onBackPressed()`. It should be simply like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```